# Regex - Get value from url

Tags: javascript, regex

Need explanation on `Regular Expression`. I have below codes,

```
function getURLParameter(url, name) {
    return (RegExp(name + '=' + '(.+?)(&|$)').exec(url)||[,null])[1];
}

var id = getURLParameter(url, 'id');
console.log(id); //1

// let say the example of url is 
// index.php?id=1&user=xxx
```

I understand the `exec()` function on js is to find the match.

What does the `RegExp()` check to get the value of 1?

I have test it on [regExr.com](http://regexr.com/) and it get the match of `id=1&`.

> **Update Question**

Sorry for the confusing question. What I need to know is on the `return statement`.

What is the use of `[1]` on

```
return (RegExp(name + '=' + '(.+?)(&|$)')
.exec(url)||[,null])[1];
```

Comment: It returns the content of group 1 or `null` if regex doesn't match.

Comment: @Toto that means on the example, it will return id=1&. Is it correct?

Comment: No, It returns the content of group 1 that is `1` it is what is present between `id=`  and `&`

Comment: @Toto understood. Thanks for the details!

Comment: The question here is not about regular expressions, but language syntax of the host code. Voting to reopen so it either gets answers or marked with the proper duplicate if one is found.